# absolute b-navbar-brand with img

Tags: vuejs2, bootstrap-vue

i have an issue with my image in navbar brand tag, also the absolute position is setted.

```
                    <header>
        <b-navbar toggleable="lg" type="dark">
            <b-navbar-brand>
                <img class="logo" src="../assets/FD49.png">
            </b-navbar-brand>
            <b-navbar-toggle target="nav-collapse"></b-navbar-toggle>
            <b-collapse is-nav>
                <b-navbar-nav>
                    <b-nav-item :to="{name: 'description'}">Description</b-nav-item>
                    <b-nav-item :to="{name:'hydrologie'}">Etat des lieux</b-nav-item>
                    <b-nav-item :to="{name:'EdL'}">Diag. et Facteurs Limitants</b-nav-item>
                    <b-nav-item :to="{name:'EdL'}">Actions préconisés et Gest.Halieutique</b-nav-item>
                </b-navbar-nav>
            </b-collapse>
            <b-nav-text class="ml-auto"><titre></titre></b-nav-text>
        </b-navbar>
    </header>
```

and here is the css

```
    .logo {
    background-color: beige;
    z-index: 9999;
    height: 8rem;
    padding: 5px; /* firefox bug fix */
    top:10px; 
    left:10px;
    width: 8rem;
    position:absolute;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

i'm working with vuejs 2 and bootstrap-vue 2.21.2
[issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pf9jo.png)

Comment: then dont use `position:absolute;`

Comment: What do you expect? And could you please describe your issue more specifically?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.